# Magento error: "Unable to read saved settings"

Tags: php, magento, ftp

I am currently trying to install magento on a new server, and when I get to the download part of the install wizard, I get this error:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Unable to read saved settings. Please check Installation Path of FTP Connection.
```

Here's the info I've enterred:

Magento Connect Channel Protocol: Http
Magento Version Stability: stable
Use Custom Permissions: No
Deployment Type: FTP Connection
(FTP info for server)

I've used this FTP info to access the server, so it is working. I've tried to chmod 777 the downloader directory, and I've moved and removed downloader/cache.cfg and downloader/connect.cfg. It still won't download, or even give me a more useful error.